# What happened to the edit dropdown?

Tags: feature-request

I remember when someone edited my post, I could see what edits were made and if necessary roll them back. Now, it seems to be gone. Did it move somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not using in-line editing, I see it on the edit page:

[image]

Note the box in the top-right corner which states if you select an older revision and save, it rolls back the post.

Comment: I do not get that. I click on the Edit link under my post and do not get the Rev dropdown. It's strange.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean by in-line editing. I have to click the link next to "edited". Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it with in-line editing, but I don't have actual edit permissions on any site, so I can't check.

Comment: @Troyen I've got edit permissions, but I can't see a dropdown (or any other way of doing it) using inline editing (i.e. left clicking on the "edit" button). I can see that dropdown if I right click on the ["edit"](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/849/edit) button and click "open link in new tab". The other way is to click "rollback" in the [revisions page](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/849/revisions) (as noted by dotnetN00b).

Answer (score 1):

As you and cypher stated in a comment to Troyen’s answer, there are links labeled “edit” and “rollback” in the revisions page.

Another (hack-ish) way to reach the non-inline edit page is by opening the “Edit” link in a new tab or window.